# Read list of IP addresses from file and return a network

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have been trying for hours using Google and stack overflow to read a list of IP addresses and return networks.  The ip address command works in the Python shell but seems to be tripping over the imported list.  I have tried stripping the new line and reading the file in multiple different ways but I keep getting an error returned.  I am sure it is something with how I am reading the file in but I just can't figure it out.

Here is the current code.  Let's call it revision number 4186!

```
import ipaddress
def process(line):
    # Output network with mask bits (192.168.0.0/24)
    try:
        return ipaddress.IPv4Interface(line).network
    except Exception:
        return print("FAIL_OR_EMPTY")
with open('ipaddrlong.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)
```

and the input file called  looks like this.  There is only the data and a newline (/n).

```
192.168.252.146/24
192.168.252.158/24
192.168.252.203/24
192.168.252.209/24
```

If I change the return line to a simple print, it looks fine to me.

```
'192.168.252.146/24', '192.168.252.158/24', '192.168.252.203/24', '192.168.252.209/24'
```

And when I try the command from the shell, it seems to work fine:

```
>>> x="192.168.0.1/24"
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Interface(x).network
IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/24')
```

But when I run the script the exception "FAIL_OR_EMPTY" is returned.

Comment: try: `process(line.strip())`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you have a problem with white-spaces after your IP-adresses, which you have to strip off the string first with something like this:

```
import ipaddress
def process(line):
    # Output network with mask bits (192.168.0.0/24)
    try:
        return print(ipaddress.IPv4Interface(line).network)
    except Exception:
        return print("FAIL_OR_EMPTY")
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = "".join(line.split())
        process(line)
```

My in.txt looks like this

```
192.168.252.146/24
192.168.252.158/24
192.168.252.203/24
192.168.252.209/24
I'm not an IP adr
192.168.252.209/24
```

Output

```
192.168.252.0/24
192.168.252.0/24
192.168.252.0/24
192.168.252.0/24
FAIL_OR_EMPTY
192.168.252.0/24
```

Comment: No luck on either.  Those changes cause the program to return a single FAIL_OR_EMPTY instead of a FAIL_OR_EMPTY for each line.  If I just print the output and not run it through ipaddress, there are no extra spaces.

Comment: I updated the answer with the whole code I'm running. It works for me. Maybe you changed something, so the whole input is passed to the process-function instead of single lines?